# MVC 4 Alternative to OleDb for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, oledb

Is there an alternative to using OleDb for reading data from an Excel spreadsheet?

I am struggling with missing resources on the remote hosting server, I am getting the following error `The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider` so need to include a reference/dependency to the Visual Studio 2010 MVC 4 project so that the published project will contain the necessary resources irrespective of missing drivers.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library.

Comment: Which is the worst idea you can do on a server. Office is not supported on a server and can hang indefinitely if an error message pops up and is never seen by anyone. Additionally, it's painfully slow.
My suggestion: use a library like EPPLUS : http://epplus.codeplex.com/. It's fast, free and has methods to bring the data into tables with a single method call

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of EPPLUS, but I need to deal with Excel from 97 onwards.